# Can createElement be used when window object is not available?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

In a Firefox bootstrapped addon at a stage that `window` object is not available yet, I would like to create an element to be kept as a template (not to be inserted at the time).

I was wondering if that is possible?
Can `createElement()` be created anywhere else other than in a `window.document`?

Comment: Because it has to be created multiple times and I can clone the template instead of creating a new one each and every time.

Comment: It is already a function and I am not sure what you have mentioned applies here. That stage is the browser start up, before any windows, documents are loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally but my stuff in an XML file (a XUL file, really) and use XHR to parse it (`.responseXML`). The [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) via [`nsIDOMParser`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/base/public/nsIDOMParser.idl) is another alternative (although doing sync file I/O during startup isn't a great idea, UX-wise...)

If you want a blank document, IIRC (?!) you can use [`nsIDocumentLoaderFactory.createBlankDocument`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/ffb8b976548b/docshell/base/nsIDocumentLoaderFactory.idl#l39).

Then you can [`.cloneNode(true)`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/base/public/nsIDOMParser.idl)/[`.importNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.importNode) from the pre-parsed DOM into (browser) windows.

Comment: Thanks Nils. That was the general idea. I routinely make a template and use `cloneNode()` in normal situations ie JavaScript?GreaseMonkey. I was thinking about the same here. XHR+Parser seems like too much work. addon starts in `sandbox` object. Is it possible to `createElement()` in `sandbox`?

Comment: A sandbox does not come with DOM stuff (unless you explicitly inject a `window` or other stuff into it yourself). And you don't need XHR + Parser, just XHR *or* Parser.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.document.createElement`

But on start of browser you have to add a event listener to listen to when `hiddenDOMWindow` is loaded.

But doing `createElement` is same overhead as `createElement` I'm pretty sure right? So you only need to createElement when need to insert, which will obviously have a window.

Comment: Thank you Blagoh. I think there is a typo. Did you mean "doing `createElement` is same overhead as `cloneNode`"? If that is the case, no, `clonNode` uses a lot less overheads. :)

Comment: Well, the big drawback with `.hiddenDOMWindow.document` is that on some platforms it will be a XUL document and on other platforms it will be a HTML document. This dictates the default XML namespace that will be used when `.createElement()` (so you better use `.createElementNS()`).

Comment: I didn't know that about `cloneNode` overhead, thanks @erosman ill have to look that up.

Comment: Please share when you find resource on overhead comparison. I would like to see so myself.